# Which parameters was a stored procedure or command executed with?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, nhibernate

We are using `nHibernate` which generates queries from `.NET` code. Occasionally, some queries get stuck in the `sp_whoisactive` list and we cannot find out why. I have a feeling that it has to do with a missing or broken parameter. When I run `sp_whoisactive`, however, I only see the parameter name (in example: `@p0`), not the actual value. Is there a way to retrieve this information while the process is still running?

Example:

```
SELECT 
    this_.Id as Id6_2_, this_.HRNumber as HRNumber6_2_, 
    this_.FirstName as FirstName6_2_, this_.LastName as LastName6_2_, 
    this_.StatusTypeID as StatusTy5_6_2_, 
    this_.PropertyId as PropertyId6_2_, this_.DepartmentGroupId as Departme7_6_2_, 
    property2_.PropertyID as PropertyID10_0_, 
    property2_.PropertyCode as Property2_10_0_, 
    property2_.LMSCode as LMSCode10_0_, property2_.PropertyName as Property4_10_0_, 
    property2_.Report as Report10_0_, department3_.Id as Id4_1_, 
    department3_.Name as Name4_1_, department3_.DisplayName as DisplayN3_4_1_ 
FROM 
    [dbo].[EmployeeDepartmentGroupView] this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [dbo].[Property] property2_ ON this_.PropertyId=property2_.PropertyID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [dbo].[DepartmentGroup] department3_ ON this_.DepartmentGroupId=department3_.Id 
WHERE 
    this_.HRNumber LIKE @p0;
```

Please note, this is automatically generated SQL from `nHibernate`.

Specs: SQL Server 2008r2

Comment: While the process is still running, perhaps `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<spid from sp_whoisactive>);`

Comment: Thanks Aaron. This shows me that there were 0 parameters, which makes me wonder if anything has been passed at all.

Comment: DBCC INPUTBUFFER doesn't show me what parameters were used and I know there were some. How can there not be a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a suspicion about which processes/procedures, etc cause the issue, could you not use SQL Profiler / Trace / extended events to get the data? - it is then fully recorded including the Parameters that were passed. - of course this would need to be running ahead of time - not any use once it's already running. However a well filtered Trace can have relatively low performance impact, so you could leave the Trace running all the time.

Here's basic how to setup a Trace/Profiler: [How To Create a Trace with SQL Server Profiler](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ht/trace.htm)

You can find better sources of info on this once you have your head round the concepts.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing.

Comment: It is not always an option to run a trace on a production machine.

Comment: If you always want to capture parameters for a specific stored proc, Extended Events are probably the lowest impact solution. A little more a of a learning curve than profiler, though ;)